# Why is this code running without vector header file?

Tags: c++, g++

I couldn't find out why is the code below working fine on my local system without including the vector header file but not on online judges or online compilers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> v(10);
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) v[i] = i;
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling the code by enabling the warning flags as `g++ -Wall -Wextra ./ex.cpp` but g++ doesn't give me any warnings at all. Removing the `#include<algorithm>` does give me the error I wanted, `identifier "vector" is undefined`, but I don't know what's the relationship between them.

Comment: Probably either your compiler's `iostream` or `algorithm` includes `vector`.  My headers don't, so this code does not compile on my machine.

Comment: In general, it's _possible_ for standard library header files to include other standard library header files, but not required for them to do so outside a few standard-mandated cases like `<iostream>` including `<ios>`.  Evidently on your implementation `<algorithm>` includes `<vector>` but the online judges' do not.

Comment: Is there a warning flag I can include so g++ can give me a warning about the same?

Comment: g++ does not have a warning flag, to my knowledge.  You can try to use the same compiler others are using.  Perhaps the online judges are using clang++.

Comment: @Shivamsaini -- Instead of relying on warning switches, know what standard components you're using in the modules you create, and [read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as to the necessary include files -- `Defined in header <vector>`.  Always include the file, even though you may think it was already included by some other module (you didn't create).

Comment: Usually the issue is with `<string>`, as so many code samples floating around on the web shows C++ code without this header when using `std::string`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your algorithm header itself includes the vector header (either directly or indirectly). Because of this, the code after the preprocessor looks the same as if you had included the vector header yourself.

You should not rely on this behavior though, as it depends on the standard library implementation you are using and can change at any time.